# Handling AccessViolation exception in try catch c#

Tags: wpf, mvvm, c#-4.0, try-catch

How to catch the AccessViolation exception in try-catch block:

here is the code below:

```
public static BP GetBloodPressure(string vendorid, string productid)
{
    BP Result = new BP();
    try
    {
        GETBPData BPreadings = new GETBPData();
        UInt16 VendorId = Convert.ToUInt16(vendorid, 16);
        UInt16 ProductId = Convert.ToUInt16(productid, 16);

        if (HealthMonitorData.HidDataTap_GetBloodPressure(VendorId, ProductId, ref BPreadings)) // error here
        {

            if (BPreadings.ucSystolic == 0 && BPreadings.ucDiastolic == 0 && BPreadings.DeviceId1 == 0 && BPreadings.DeviceId2 == 0 && BPreadings.ucPulse == 0)
            {
                Result = null;

            }
            else
            {
                Result.UcSystolic = BPreadings.ucSystolic;
                Result.UcDiastolic = BPreadings.ucDiastolic;
                Result.UcPulse = BPreadings.ucPulse;
                Result.DeviceId1 = BPreadings.DeviceId1;
                Result.DeviceId2 = BPreadings.DeviceId2;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
        return Result;
}
```

I am importing one dll to read the blood pressure values from the device. I have try to catch the exception but the control does not go beyond the "if" statement where the access violation exception is coming.

Kindly Suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Fix your code, dont catch those exceptions.

Comment: also,How to fix my code as am using the external dll.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handling of AccessViolationExceptions and other [corrupted state exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) has been changed in .NET 4. Generally you should *not* catch these exceptions, so the runtime has been changed to reflect this. If you really need to catch these, you must annotate the code with the `HandledProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute.

Please keep in mind, that the behavior was changed with good reason. Most applications will not be able to handle these exceptions in any meaningful way and thus should not catch them.

Comment: Hi,I have put the attribute but getting error like Error (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference). Thanks

Comment: @Tarun: Did you remember to import the `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices` namespace?

Answer (score 2):

its HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions not HandleDProcessCorruptedStateExceptions